# Interesting question on signed measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

I have managed to do the first part, but I am stuck on the second. I compelted the first part by considering $ A \cap (E_1 \backslash E_2) \subset E_1$ and $A \cap (E_1 \backslash E_2) \subset E_2^c$ and writing $A \cap E_1 = (A \cap E_1 \cap E_2) \cup (A \cap(E_1 \backslash E_2)$. I was not able to produce a similar result for the second equation.

Thanks

edit: Here is a possible attempt, but I think it's incorrect:

Write $A \cap E_1^c = (A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2) \cup (A \cap (E_1^c \backslash E_2))$

Now, we have $(A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2) \subset E_1^c$ and $ \subset E_2$ hence we have $\nu ((A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2)) = 0$ therefore using $A \cap E_1^c = (A \cap E_1^c \cap E_2) \cup (A \cap (E_1^c \backslash E_2))$ we get $\nu (A \cap E_1^c) = \nu  (A \cap (E_1^c \backslash E_2))$  now we repeat the exact same arguement with $A\cap E_2^c \cap E_1$ leading to $\nu(A \cap E_2^c ) = \nu(A \cap (E_2^c \backslash E_1))$ then is it right ot say: $A \cap (E_2^c \backslash E_1) = A \cap (E_1^c \backslash E_2)$?